# Does shared_ptr still own its object when calling the deleter?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter and in that deleter, I would like to take a temporary copy of the original `std::shared_ptr`. Expressed in code form:

```
struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{};

void deleter(Foo *f)
{
  {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> tmp = f->shared_from_this(); // Line A
  }
  delete f;
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo, &deleter);
}
```

My question is: on line *A*, can anything be said about the call of `shared_from_this()`? Is it legal? If so, does the standard say anything about its return value? If we replace `enable_shared_from_this` with a different `weak_ptr` or global reference to `foo`, will the answer be the same?

[Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6872a321b79a2e26) with libc++ and [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa925bd1f20bd42) with libstdc++ both produce code which terminates on a `bad_weak_ptr` exception, but I can't seem to trace this as *required* by the standard. Is this implementation-specific, or am I missing a rule?

All the relevant rules I found (quoting C++11):

> **20.7.2.2.2 `shared_ptr` destructor**
>
> 1 ... if `*this` *owns* an object `p` and a deleter `d`, `d(p)` is called
>   2 [*Note:* ... Since the destruction of `*this` decreases the number of instances that share ownership with `*this`
>   by one, after `*this` has been destroyed all `shared_ptr` instances that shared ownership with `*this` will
>   report a `use_count()` that is one less than its previous value. *—end note*]
>
> **20.7.2.2.5 `shared_ptr` observers**
>
> 7 `use_count` *Returns:* the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that share ownership with `*this`, or 0
>   when `*this` is empty.

To me, it seems it's not clear whether the decrement of `use_count` happens before or after the call of the deleter. Is getting `bad_weak_ptr` a reliable result, or is this simply unspecified?

Note that I am intentionally avoiding a situation where a pointer like `tmp` in my example code would outlive the deleter execution.

Comment: `I would like to take a temporary copy of the original std::shared_ptr` 0_0, why?!

Comment: If you don't want `tmp` to outlive the scope of the deleter, why not use the raw pointer `Foo *f`?

Comment: @DavidHaim Long story about a complex framework of interface management, ABI compatibility, and casts between virtual base classes, all built on top of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @DanielTrugman Same as my previous reply to David Haim: legacy code reasons.

Comment: @Angew instead, I would add some virtual function to Foo named "move" which moves the content of the pointer. if the deleter decides it's not the time for the object to die, it moves it rather than increase the ref count

Comment: @Angew: Maybe you can just make a dummy ``shared_ptr`` with a no-op deleter: ``shared_ptr<Foo>{f, [](Foo*){}}`` Of course, if a copy of this ``shared_ptr`` persists, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: Common sense dictates that the deleter is called because the last owning ptr has released the object. What the text says is a bit unclear, but you should go with common sense.

Answer (score 13):

consider

> [c++14-12.4-15]Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists;

and

> [c++14-20.8.2.4-7]**shared_from_this**()[...]Requires: enable_shared_from_this shall be an accessible base class of T. *this shall be a subobject of an object t of type T. **There shall be at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns &t**.

so, considering that the deleter is invoked by the shared_ptr destructor, calling shared_from_this() in the deleter of the last shared_ptr owning it results in undefined behaviour.

EDIT: as pointed out by YSC, in **C++17** shared_from_this() is required to behave as the corresponding weak_ptr conversion call. This complicates matters though, because it's not clear what weak_ptr::expired() should return at deleter call ... anyway, taking the quoted `20.7.2.2.2` note literally, a bad_weak_ptr should be raised in this case.

Comment: I don't get how 12.4-15 is relevant here. What destructor are you considering here?

Comment: Ok then, `main::foo` does not exist once we enter `deleter()`. Why does it matter?

Comment: @YSC, because if foo does not exist, you are violating a shared_from_this() precondition ...

Comment: In deed! I do get it now. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this): _"It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17) `std::bad_weak_ptr` is thrown (by the `shared_ptr` constructor from a default-constructed `weak_this`) (since C++17). "_

Comment: @YSC, thank you for pointing out the c++17 change, adding to answer for completness sake ...

Comment: On the contrary, an object that exists enough in its destructor to pass the this pointer to other objects and the language goes out of its way to provide sane behavior if you call virtual methods in this state. Now if you try to downcast to a derived class all bets are off.

Comment: @Joshua The std says that the lifetime ends when the dtor begins, then tries to make that irrelevant by defining what the ending of the lifetime made undefined